# call focusout inside focusin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call focusout event inside focusin becouse I want to use previous value from focusin event, but focusout event executes many times

```
$('tr #edituser').focusin(function(){
      var prev_uname = $(this).text();
      $('tr #edituser').focusout(function(){
          alert();            
      });
  });
```

how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you `focusin` you attach a new `focusout` event to `'tr #edituser'. That is why it gets called multiple times.

Try [This](http://jsfiddle.net/apox5j4z/)

```
var prev_uname;
$('tr #editUser').on('focusin', function(){
   prev_uname = $(this).val();
   console.log(prev_uname)

});

$('tr #editUser').focusout(function(){
   alert(prev_uname);            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted to know how to 'call' the focusout event handler, here you go:

```
$('tr #edituser').focusin(function() {
    var prev_uname = $(this).text();
    $('tr #edituser').trigger('focusout');
});

$('tr #editUser').focusout(function() {
   alert();        
});
```

From the jQuery documentation of the [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function.

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.